# SVN merge between 2 branch which are created from different source

Tags: svn, merge

I am new to SVN merging strategy, I am trying to perform merge between two branches using below commands but I am getting more than 100 conflicts which is not expected. These 2 branches are created from different sources, can you please tell me is this the right command I am using or is there something else I need to do.

```
svn merge --reintegrate <branch>
svn merge <branch>
```

I have tried using these 2 commands but I see the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't reintegrate  unrelated (parent-child) branches
2. In order to reintegrate branch B into A you **must** *before* reintegration attempt merge divergent changes from A to B
3. Your merge command is **terribly dirty** - now it means in human readable form "merge changes from `svn` subdir in working copy into `merge` subdir of the same WC". I suppose, you want something different
4. Read SVN Book or at least `svn help merge` carefully
5. Merging `SOMEPATH` into `ANOTHER` path is really easy task (in theory)

It will be (with all preliminary steps)

```
svn co URL/TO/ANOTHER
cd ANOTHER
svn merge URL/TO/SOMEPATH
```